# using mfc to get process network statistics

Tags: windows, networking, mfc

Now I'am working on a MFC program. What I want to know is the speed a process receive/send to the network. Suppose I have a process named chrome.exe, it may receive 1008B/s, send 2987B/s. I know I can get what I want in the Win 7 Resource Monitor. But how can I get those data in my program. Dose MFC or Win32api support this?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain this information, as well as a wealth of other performance data using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394597%28VS.85%29.aspx):

[Monitoring Performance Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

This class is probably what you are looking for:

[Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394293%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

From a native C++/MFC application, you'll access WMI through some [COM interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Have fun!

Comment: Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface has something to do with it. But I can't get the info that I want for a particular process. I can know the cpu and memory usage from the Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process. But I can't get what I want from this class.